# Anaconda3 Installation on Ubuntu 21, on Raspberrypi 4

Tags: anaconda, ubuntu-18.04, raspberry-pi4, anaconda3, qiskit

I am following instructions to teach myself qiskit (Quantum computing developer Kit) from https://qiskit.org/documentation/getting_started.html, which requires Anaconda 3. For this learning exercise I plan to use a RPi4 running Ubuntu 21.X on it. I installed [64-Bit (AWS Graviton2 / ARM64) Installer (413 M)](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). The installation hit a block when at the prompt to initialize conda , I get an error: `line 477:  5128 Illegal instruction     $PREFIX/bin/conda init` which is further described as an open issue here on [GitHub](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10723).

Would like to know if anyone have had success with Anaconda on RPi4b and even better, have been able to use qiskit on any OS. [I see the mambaforge / mini forge options but I am not sure qiskit is going to be compatible for conda versions provided by mamba/miniforge.]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Anaconda installer on RPi4 as it was compiled for AWS Graviton2 architecture.

Have you tried miniforge? It should work fine on RPi4

Comment: I have since tried miniforge and the conda installation was clean. However, the subsequent qiskit installation failed for some backend dependencies which I'll explore options. Thanks for your response.